# Слово "рта" - единственное или множественное число?

Tags: число

Слово "рта" - жен. род, стар. рты, лыжи. Приидоша мордва на ртах, с сулицами и рогатинами.

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/350026

Сам Даль не определяет слово как существительное множественного числа, но всё-таки в определении чётко указывает, что это именно лыжи, а не лыжа. Так всё-таки "рта" - единственное или множественное число?

Comment: Вы не очень внимательно прочитали. У Даля **указывается**, что "рта" - ед. число. Потому, что родительный - **рты**.. Для словарной статьи этого обычно достаточно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Слово “рта”-единственное или множественное число?

**Единственное.**

Из "Словаря церковно-славянского и русского языка" середины 19-го века:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С вашего позволения: век XIX.

Comment: Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
 _"Корректно: XVII века. **Допустимый вариант: 17-го века**"._
 http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=17-%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Добрый день! Подскажите, пож-та, как надописать:
1. Художники 17 века
2. Художники XVII века.
Вот откуда нынче знания черпают! Каков вопрос, таков и ответ.                                                                                                                     Заглянем в Вики:                                                                                   В русском языке римские цифры используются в следующих случаях:

Номер века или тысячелетия: XIX век, II тысячелетие до н. э.
Порядковый номер монарха
Номер корпуса в Вооруженных силах
Группа крови на нашивках формы в ВС.

Comment: Номер тома в многотомной книге (иногда — номера частей книги, разделов или глав).
В некоторых изданиях — номера листов с предисловием к книге, чтобы не исправлять ссылки внутри основного текста при изменении предисловия.
Маркировка циферблатов часов «под старину».
Иные важные события или пункты списка, например: V постулат Евклида, II мировая война, XX съезд КПСС, Игры XXII Олимпиады и т. п.
Валентность химических элементов.
Порядковый номер ступени в звукоряде.

Comment: База гомеопатических разведений (Conium X3, Aconitum C200 и т. п.).
В математическом анализе римскими цифрами иногда записывается номер производной выше третьей

Comment: _shampar: "Заглянем в Вики: В русском языке римские цифры **используются** в следующих случаях: Номер века или тысячелетия: XIX век..."_ === 

Ну, используются. Но разве Вики говорит о том, что никакие другие варианты для обозначения номера века **нельзя** использовать?

Comment: Правила языка не приравнять к ПДД, они сродни пешеходному движению, запреты не работают, ибо не бывает смертельных столкновений. Но попробуй-ка ходить по левой встречной стороне!

Comment: Во времена Пушкина движение, конечно, было не таким интенсивным, как в наше время. Может, потому он и не боялся "ходить по левой встречной стороне"? === Из его письма Горчакову: _«Я в нём хотел изобразить это равнодушие к жизни и к её наслаждениям, эту преждевременную старость души, которые сделались отличительными чертами молодёжи **19-го века**»._

Comment: Не стоит путать личную и открытую для всех переписку.